# Popout the child from parent overflow:scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am struggling with this problem. I have a vertical menu list which is inside a div with overflow set to 'scroll' (I tried with auto as well). If I hover over a item in the menu with the (overflow set to scroll) set, the menu values are not being displayed. Here is the image which is how it is displayed.[image: error]

Here is the code for the above situation.[Not Working](https://jsfiddle.net/aryasobn/3z8mq4k3/)

Here is the css part of the code which causes a lot of trouble:

```
            .sidebar{
                  position: absolute;
                  top: 0px;
                  right:0px;
                  text-align: center;
                  font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
                  line-height: 30px;
                  padding-left: 10px;
                  z-index: 10;
                  float:right;
                  margin-right:20px;
                  height: 100px;
                  //overflow:scroll; //This is the code to be changed
            }

            .sidebar ul{
                z-index:25;
            }

            .insideul{
                overflow: scroll;
            }

            #mainist li{
                z-index:50;
            }
```

Here is the working image.  [image: working]

Here is the working code if I remove the overflow. [working](https://jsfiddle.net/aryasobn/uvx38d19/)

Can someone help me with the above error.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I just removed the '`overflow: scroll`' rule from the `.insideul` class and everything worked.

Comment: catalyst is correct. in your fiddle remove  
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: auto;
from .sidebar

Answer (score 0):

I just comment out the overflow-x: auto and overflow-flow: auto in the .sideBar class, it works.

https://jsfiddle.net/3z8mq4k3/1/

```
 .sidebar{
              position: absolute;
              top: 0px;
              right:0px;
              text-align: center;
              font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
              line-height: 30px;
              padding-left: 10px;
              z-index: 10;
              float:right;
              margin-right:20px;
              height: 700px;
              /*overflow-x: auto;
              overflow-y: auto;*/
        }
```

Comment: I want the scrollbar. I have a huge amount of data.